# Replay Philips Livingcolors remote signal

Tags: identification, remote-control, zigbee, reverse-engineering

I have a [Phillips Living Colors Lamp](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Philips-LivingColors-Changing-Integrated-Control/dp/B008B4DC84), which comes with a remote control. I'd like to be able to capture/replay the signal of the remote control so I can control the lamp with a microcontroller (Arduino).

I have no idea which kind of signal the remote uses (infrared/bluetooth/...). Does anyone know how I can find out which signal the remote uses and how I can capture and replay the signal cost efficiently?

I already managed to capture & replay a TV remote IR signal with an Arduino using [this tutorial](http://www.righto.com/2009/09/arduino-universal-remote-record-and.html).

Comment: It seems to me that some kind of RF is involved, I don't see any IR receiver. You should disassemble the remote and show us its bowels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Living Colors series has two versions (AFAIK). Generation 1, which the remotes used a MSP430 microcontroller connected to a CC2500 RF Transceiver which pairs with another CC2500 in the lamp itself. Because there is an open bus between the two, someone (Sprite_TM a very awesome hacker) [reverse engineered the protocol between the CC2500 and the MSP430 (PDF)](http://www.ideetron.nl/Livcol/UK2008110661.pdf).

[All you need is a CC2500 module and the right code to make your own](http://www.knutsel.org/2010/04/11/using-the-cc2500-arduino-shield/). http://www.knutsel.org/ has a ton of info on it, including an arduino shield.

The Generation 2 aka Smartlink, did away with the CC2500 and MSP430, and went with a single chip CC2530 System on Chip Zigbee IC. So there is no way to sniff the protocol between the chip. And the wireless protocol is encrypted, so even with a Zigbee sniffer, you cannot know what commands to use. **The one you link to is a Generation 2 Livingcolors**.

But tada, Phillips has released more Zigbee based products, including the Hue Bridge, essentially a HTTP based Ethernet-to-Zigbee bridge [which can be paired with the Gen 2 Livingcolors lamps.](http://www.everyhue.com/vanilla/discussion/7/hue-and-living-colors/p1) [And throw in an open API](http://blog.ef.net/2012/11/02/philips-hue-api.html), [as well as a ethernet or wifi shield](http://www.everyhue.com/vanilla/discussion/747/hue-bridge-and-arduino-wifi-shield-no-response/p1), [you get arduino control.](https://github.com/oguime/Hue_W5100_HT6P20B) [(Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRcG0C0mo08)